# How to get Ubuntu AppIndicator icon coordinates

Tags: application-development, indicator, pygi

I'm working on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 and create software built on top of GTK+ 3 using pygobject.

I've got a task of showing popup windows just below the app indicator icon of my application and I can't figure out how can I get my app indicator icon coordinates. Seems like app_indicator object does not possess Gdk window to work with (or at least it's not publically visible through its properties).

I'd be appreciate for any help or direction of how to get app indicator icon coordinates directly or make some workaround to figure out them.

Comment: If you have to display something like a notification from your app, why not do it with notify-osd like many other apps do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is intentionally no way to easily discover them.  We don't want an interaction with the indicators that is not a menu and an icon.  This consistency is important to the type of experience that we're trying to create.  The wiki page has information on the [design rational of the menubar](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MenuBar).