# How to determine last coordinates and posiiton of application window / screen

Tags: window-manager, window, log, interface

I need to determine the last state of an application window when it was closed (by way of signing out of Ubuntu 14.04). The app in this specific case is QT though I am interested in the question for all apps if possible. I have reviewed the link below but would like to confirm that there are no logs or other system resources that record the last coordinates and position of an app's user interface / window / screen. Any and all input is helpful (for example, app specific logs, O/S logs or resources, etc.). Thank you!

[How to get Ubuntu AppIndicator icon coordinates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289019/how-to-get-ubuntu-appindicator-icon-coordinates)

Comment: For what purpose would you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remembering Window Positions (and preferrably sizes, too) in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493824/remembering-window-positions-and-preferrably-sizes-too-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do so. Ubuntu with default Unity desktop can remember  **window** positions via `compiz`'s  Place Windows plugin. See also this: http://askubuntu.com/a/387910/295286   For other desktops it can be scripted, but for default Ubuntu it's not exactly necessary.  As for Ubuntu AppIndicators, those aren't windows, they're basically drop-down menus, so their icon positions cannot be recorded, at least in any current Unity version.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the possible duplicate issue though this is not quite the issue and I apologize if I confused. I can certainly install a tool to store this information as suggested in the other, prior post but I have a case where I need to find interface positions / coordinates on a machine from the past (where only existing OS resources are in place). So, I hope this clarifies the issue. Thank you all the same!